# LINQ - select filename and filesize together from Directory.EnumerateFiles

Tags: c#, linq

The following LINQ query gives me all files in the specified directory that meet the where clause, in this case filetype and size.

```
public static List<string> getFs(string sDir)
{

    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(
            s => ((s.ToLower().EndsWith(".ai")) ||
                  (s.ToLower().EndsWith(".psd") && new FileInfo(s).Length > 10000000) ||
                  (s.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf") && new FileInfo(s).Length > 10000000)
                 ) 
               )
       .Select(
                 s => s.Replace(sDir, "")
               );   

    return files.ToList();
}
```

At present the file name is returned. I'd like to have the query return both the file name and file size and was wondering how I would incorporate that into the select part?

I am unsure how to select multiple fields in a LINQ query and would be grateful for any pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Using DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles() would seem a little more efficient here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and creating a FileInfo, you can use `DirectoryInfo` class:

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(sDir).GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(
        s => ((s.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith(".ai")) ||
                (s.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith(".psd") && s.Length > 10000000) ||
                (s.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf") && s.Length > 10000000)
                )
            )
    .Select(
                s => new { FileName = s.FullName.Replace(sDir, ""), Length = s.Length }
            );
```

In this way you have what you want, but you cannot return the result form a function, because a method's return type cannot be an anonymous type. You can create a custom class, or you can use the new `Tuple` class:

```
public static List<Tuple<string, long>> getFs(string sDir)
{
    var files = new DirectoryInfo(sDir).GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(
            s => ((s.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith(".ai")) ||
                    (s.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith(".psd") && s.Length > 10000000) ||
                    (s.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf") && s.Length > 10000000)
                    )
                )
        .Select(
                    s => new Tuple<string, long>(s.FullName.Replace(sDir, ""), s.Length)
                );

    return files.ToList();
}
```

Usage of the method is like this:

```
foreach( var t in getFs(@"C:\\Windows\") )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "File name: {0}, File size: {1}", t.Item1, t.Item2 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use an anonymous type:

Something like this:

```
.Select(s => new 
{ 
    fileName = s.Replace(sDir, ""), 
    size = new FileInfo(s).Length 
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [use anonymous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) type:

```
public static List<string> getFs(string sDir)
{

    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(
            s => ((s.ToLower().EndsWith(".ai")) ||
                  (s.ToLower().EndsWith(".psd") && new FileInfo(s).Length > 10000000) ||
                  (s.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf") && new FileInfo(s).Length > 10000000)
                 ) 
               )
       .Select(
                 s => new { s.Replace(sDir, ""), s.Lenght}
               );   

    return files.ToList();
}
```